# Turning Internet Connectivity off with Robotium

Tags: android, testing, robotium

Is it possible to turn internet connectivity (data/wi-fi) off/on through Robotium if the app itself does not have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible in direct way without permission to do it.

You can create another application with that permission, this application should have implemented broadcast receiver for getting broadcast messages for turning on/off wifi and this way you can send broadcast messages from your android test to this application.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do it without any permissions (Tested on API 20). I will not write the code here as you would end up getting to realize one thing... As soon as you disables data (aka network) the emulator gets disconnected and your tests fail. It seems that it's a bug. Maybe it's not a problem on Genymotion. I haven't tried it.

If you'd like to try that I am not kidding do this:

1. start your app in debug mode
2. stop on a breakpoint
3. from command line issue `adb shell svc data disable`
4. now all tests should be down.

In general the solution that does not require any permission is calling the adb from the java code.